# powershell remove all permissions on a folder for a specific user

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory

I need a script or simple powershell code for removing all permissions to a folder for specific user, by inheriting these deletion to all the subfolders and files as well - recursively...
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 $acl=get-acl c:\temp
 $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\user","Read",,,"Allow")
 $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)
 Set-Acl -Path "c:\temp" -AclObject $acl
```

this should wipe all security rules for user in c:\temp recursively

Comment: Hi Kayasax, thanks one more time for the support. It help this last code, but not removing recursively?! Could you please review it once again..thanks in advance!

Comment: really ? this has done the trick on my workstation... 
you can try 
`ls c:\temp -recurse |set-acl -aclObject $acl`

Comment: you mean trying like this:  $acl=get-acl c:\temp
 $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\user","Read",,,"Allow")
 $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)
 ls C:\temp -recurse | set-acl -aclObject $acl

Comment: It seems with the last code is working perfectly...it takes much longer-normally, but seems fine...and for giving roles except full controll and special permission to one user, we can use the same logic...$acl=get-acl c:\temp $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\user","Read",,,"Allow‌​") $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule) ls C:\temp -recurse | set-acl -aclObject $acl , we should use AddAccessRule instead of removeaccessrule all...so it should look like?

Comment: I got "Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." I am running as administrator. Please help.

Comment: @AdityaBokade try to take ownership prior to set acl (use [takeown.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/takeown.html) )

Comment: @LoïcMICHEL One Help Plz. I have created PS Script to create web app on local IIS. On TFS build I created step to run the PS. Upon build it says script executed successfully, but it won't. What could be the reason?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384496/deploy-asp-net-web-app-on-local-or-remote-iis-using-powershell-dsc

Comment: None of this works for .Net Core. Using `Set-Acl` needs to be done very carefully as it will set the entire security descriptor. `SetAccessControl` is a smarter choice.

Answer (score 2):

i think the simpler way to do this is to copy acl from a file or folder that have the correct permissions and apply it to the folder where you want specific access.
example:

```
$acl= get-acl /path/to/file_with_correct acl 
$files = get-childItem c:\temp\*.* -recurce | set-acl -aclobject $acl -whatif
```

remove the -whatif parameter to effectively modify acl

Or follow [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730951.aspx) and use a code like :

```
$Right = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly  
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 

$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\bob") 
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
    ($objUser, $Right, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 
$objACL = Get-ACL "d:\test" 
$objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll($objACE) 
Set-ACL "d:\test" -AclObject $objACL
```

Comment: Thank you Kayasax for the reply, but coukld you please give an example, if lets say from D:\Test path-location, I need to remove all permissions to this folder for user with name bob...

Comment: example: $acl= get-acl D:\Test 
$files= get-childItem $acl -recurce | set-acl -aclobject $acl -whatif.....and where I'm specifying the object for the user?! where i have to write user bob and where im defining that im removing the permissions...

Comment: Hi Kayasax, im getting the error below on executing this ps1:

Comment: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "FileSystemAccessRule" and the argument count: "5".
At line:7 char:21
+ $objACE = New-Object <<<<  System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule `
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Exception calling "RemoveAccessRuleAll" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: rule"
At line:10 char:28
+ $objACL.RemoveAccessRuleAll <<<< ($objACE) 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: line edited :  `$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($objUser, $Right, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) `

Comment: ok progress is there, no error, but no access has been delete, shall i update the first row from $Right = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Read" to $Right = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Full" so my question is to remove all the give permision to that users, and recursively to all the subfolders/files to that path...thank you very much..highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This function that I created will invoke the scriptBlock for you on the target machine to remove the permissions for a user.

```
function Remove-OGRemoteACL (){
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Invoke a script block on a target to remove ACL permissions

.DESCRIPTION
Invoke a script block on a target to change ACL permissions to remove the crazy delay GET-ACL can encounter.

.PARAMETER serverFQDN
the server that the script block is run on

.PARAMETER remotePath
the UNC path of the share to remove the permisions for the user from.

.PARAMETER userName
the user name of the domain user.

.EXAMPLE
Remove-OGRemoteACL -serverFQDN "bigserver.awesomedomain.net" -remotePath "\\bigserver.awesomedomain.net\my\amazingShare" -userName "awesomedomain\myuser"

.NOTES
    Name:       Remove-OGRemoteACL
    Author:     Richie Schuster - SCCMOG.com
    GitHub:     https://github.com/SCCMOG/PS.SCCMOG.TOOLS
    Website:    https://www.sccmog.com
    Contact:    @RichieJSY
    Created:    2023-03-14
    Updated:    -

    Version history:
    1.0.0 - 2023-03-14 Function Created
#>
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$serverFQDN,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=1)]
    [string]$remotePath,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]$userName
)
try{
    Write-Verbose "Invoking ACL removal commmand [Server: $($serverFQDN)] [userName: $($userName)] [Server: $($remotePath)]"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "$($serverFQDN)" -ScriptBlock { 
        $acl = Get-Acl $using:remotePath
        $usersid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount("$using:userName")
        $acl.PurgeAccessRules($usersid)
        $acl | Set-Acl $using:remotePath
    }
    Write-Verbose "Success invoking ACL removal commmand [Server: $($serverFQDN)] [userName: $($userName)] [Server: $($remotePath)]"
}
catch{
    Write-Error "Error - Failed invoking ACL removal commmand [Server: $($serverFQDN)] [userName: $($userName)] [Server: $($remotePath)]. Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

}

Example:

```
Remove-OGRemoteACL -serverFQDN "bigserver.awesomedomain.net" -remotePath "\\bigserver.awesomedomain.net\my\amazingShare" -userName "awesomedomain\myuser" -Verbose
```