# Added permission not inherited to sub folders/files

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory, addition

Im trying to add modify right to bob user from domain, but it is giving only permission and no rights at all and even not inheriting to subfolder to path `D:\test`, from the script as below:

```
$Right = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::InheritOnly  
$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("domain\bob") 

$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, $Right, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 

$objACL = Get-ACL "D:\Test"
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)
Set-ACL "D:\Test" -aclobject $objACL
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: i dont think this is a good idea to open a [second post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513863/powershell-remove-all-permissions-on-a-folder-for-a-specific-user) for the same question. Did you even get an eye on the links i gave you ?

Comment: Dear kayasax, i full went throught the links< which u send to me and also asked you regarding the adding the permissions recursively to al the folders and subfolders, as Im updating the InheritanceFlags and PropagationFlags with the possible values for inheriting the "modify" permisisons to all the subfolder for specific user, but it is giving access only to the path is written to the script, in this case only to D:\test folder...any suggestion is welcomed...thank you for your understaning!

Comment: also your links were ok, but for removing the permission and unfortunately, they were removing the permissions for all the users, if the path was given by maint root, like D:\, were removing all the permissing for all the users to all the folders, not only to specific defined users, and on specifying like D:\test path were remiving permissions onky yo that path, and recursively to subfolder...so that was for removeruleacces but for addin recursively i miss this information,,thankyou...

Comment: allright sorry i must have read your post too fast. i dont have an idea for now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "only permission and no rights at all", but the following line is what prevents your ACL from being inherited:

```
$InheritanceFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None
```

Change that line to

```
$InheritanceFlag = ([System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ContainerInherit, [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::ObjectInherit)
```

and the ACL should be inherited by the child objects.