# Deploy asp.net web app on local or remote IIS using PowerShell DSC

Tags: powershell, continuous-deployment, dsc

I am unable to find any help on how to use PowerShell for DSC and deploy asp.net web app on local or remote on premises IIS.

Can you please help me with the steps or any resources?

Answer (score 0):

What's your preferred method of deploying code prior to using DSC?  xRobocopy was created with this scenario in mind, but if you are packaging your solution using NuGet, you could also use the PackageManagement resource.

I started working on a NuGet based config script recently but it isn't ready to publish in the gallery yet:
https://github.com/Microsoft/NuGetIISAppServerConfig/blob/master/NuGetIISAppServerConfig.ps1