# Remove all permissions to a file, except the owner of the file

Tags: powershell

I would like to do something similar to [How to Remove all permissions for a specific user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513863/powershell-remove-all-permissions-on-a-folder-for-a-specific-user), but I want to remove all access to the file for *everybody* except the owner of the file.

Is it possible to do that in a relatively clean way?

I suppose I could call `get-acl C:\users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\TheFile.txt` and then walk through all the users listed there, and remove all rights for each one (as described in the linked question above), but is there an easier way?

Comment: Define "easier"

Comment: `icacls TheFile.txt /grant:r username:f /inheritance:r` - removes all inherited and explicit permisions, and grants full control to 'username'. Is that easier?

Comment: Don't believe so, think you are on the right track with looping through the files getting the owner via the Get-ACL cmdlet, then following the same process as what you cited

Comment: I tested the suggestion provided by TessellatingHeckler . It should be the easiest way . "get-acl" may help you get the owner ,then use icacls.exe to set the permission .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examplecode in a function (Put it simply in the same Scriptfile, above all your own code):

```
function Remove-ACLEntries
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string]$File
    )
    $authusers = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 'S-1-5-11').Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value
    $acl = Get-Acl $File
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $False)
    $owner = $acl.owner;
    For($i=$acl.Access.Count - 1; $i -gt 0; $i--)
    {
        $rule = $acl.Access[$i]
        if ($rule.IdentityReference -ne $owner -or $rule.IdentityReference -eq $authusers) 
        {
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
        }
    }
    Set-ACL -Path $file -AclObject $acl | Out-Null
}
```

Usage Single File:

```
Remove-ACLEntries -File c:\your\path\to\file.txt
```

Usage Multiple Files:

```
$files = Get-Childitem c:\your\path -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files){ Remove-ACLEntries -File $file.Fullname }
```

Attention: The User you are using to operate this function must have fullaccess to the file by himself. If the function don't working, try to run the powershell in Adminmode.

Greetings, Ronny

Comment: Ronny, sweet answer. Thank you!

Comment: Very nice - but when I ran it - it removed ALL ACLs - included those previously granted for the owner.

Comment: This doesn't remove Authenticated Users entry.

Answer (score 2):

The example below removes all the ACLs and sets the ACL to allow Full Control for the owner of the file.

```
$acl = Get-Acl "$filePath"
$object = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount($acl.owner)
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($acl.owner,"FullControl","Allow")
$acl.SetOwner($object)
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
#$acl.SetAccessRule($sysUserAccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl "$filePath"
```

Comment: Excellent. I was looking for an example of how to use `New-Object` for an access rule for a single file, rather than for a directory (for which propagation options can be set)

Comment: I commented out `$acl.SetAccessRule($sysUserAccessRule)`, because `$sysUserAccessRule` isn't referenced elsewhere. Setting `$filePath` should be intuitive. Other than that, I can confirm that this code works.

Comment: This is a very concise and efficient solution, and I can confirm it works perfectly, and that the `sysUserAccessRule` is not needed.